# Why are there $F$-symbols in the splitting in anyon theory?

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

I am learning some basic knowledge of anyon theory by reading P. Bonderson's thesis: http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/2447/2/thesis.pdf.

$F$-symbols and $R$-symbols are two basic operations on anyons (see Chap 2 for the very nice introduction of $F$-symbols and $R$-symbols.).

In Chapter 2.5.1, I was told that $F$-symbols are generally not gauge invariant. Then this is my puzzle:

In P. Bonderson's paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.2726.pdf, he studies the energy splitting due to anyon tunneling. And the size of energy splitting is given in Eq.(8) therein, which contains $F$-symbol. It seems to me the energy splitting is a physical observable, and thus gauge invariant. So I cannot understand why there is $F$-symbol in the energy splitting.

Can anyone explain this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The splitting is not just $F$ symbols. There are also non-universal tunneling amplitudes $\Gamma_e$, which will compensate for the gauge transformations of $F$. In the end of the day, what we may learn from this kind of general consideration is usually some (gauge-invariant) generic relations. For example, in the Eq. 24 of the paper, we have $E_1^{(1)}/E_0^{(1)}=-d_1^{-1}$ for spin $1/2$ anyon in $SU(2)_k$, which should be a gauge-invariant relation.

Comment: Hi @Meng Cheng, thanks very much. It clears up my confusion.